# Grep and Text processing

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have these files;

```
*_NOMm6xR.res
*_NOMm5xR.res
*_NOMm4xR.res
*_NOMm3xR.res
*_NOMm2xR.res
 *35LS05*.res 
*_NOMm1xR.res
*_NOM_SRP.res
 *35LE50*.res 
*_NOMp1xR.res
*_NOMp2xR.res
*_NOMp3xR.res
*_NOMp4xR.res
*_NOMp5xR.res
*_NOMp6xR.res
*_NOMp7xR.res
*_NOM_C2P.res
```

content of above files;

```
dynAB 1193.95, Intrusion2mal -0.16, TIME 0.00400002, Value MAX 1194.11, Value MIN 1194.03
```

I want result file dynAB.txt with following format;

```
           Value MAX   Value MIN   TIME         dynAB
_NOMm6xR : 1194.11,    1194.03,    0.00400002,  1193.95,
_NOMm5xR :
_NOMm4xR :
_NOMm3xR :
_NOMm2xR :
  35LS05 :
_NOMm1xR :
_NOM_SRP :
  35LE50 :
_NOMp1xR :
_NOMp2xR :
_NOMp3xR :
_NOMp4xR :
_NOMp5xR :
_NOMp6xR :
_NOMp7xR :
_NOM_C2P :
```

Comment: do u literally have those asterisk in the filename?

Comment: no... due to confidentiality i can not mention entire file name.
i use ll -tr or ls in linux

Comment: and i need same sequence (shown file listing)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  We can't comment on your code without seeing it.  Suggestion -- you need a `perl` script, not `grep`.

Comment: grep -i "intru" *_NOMm6xR.res | cut -d "," -f1 | sort > res1.txt
but this does not print file name in the begining..

Comment: try adding the `-H`  flag to `grep`

Comment: -H is also useful,
output looks like  
x_x_xxx_xxxxxx_xxxxx_NOMm6xR.resu:dynAB 1189.83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the exact output, but close:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{ OFS="\t"; print "Filename","Value_MAX","Value_MIN","TIME","dynAB" }
    FNR == 1 { OFS="\t"; print FILENAME,$9,$12,$6,$2 }
' *.res
```

Output:

```
Filename      Value_MAX  Value_MIN  TIME         dynAB
_NOMm6xR.res  1194.11,   1194.03    0.00400002,  1193.95,
```

Comment: I have tested;
awk 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t"; print "Simulation","Value_MAX","Value_MIN","TIME","dynAB" } FNR == 1 { OFS="\t"; print Simulation,$9,$12,$6*1000,$2 } ' *.res > test.txt

and output is;

Simulation Value_MAX Value_MIN TIME dynAB
 1194.11, 1194.03 4.00007 1193.95,

Is it possible to refine it further since filename is missing and the columns are not properly oriented under relevent headers.

Note: I have added '*1000' to have rounded values.

Comment: `FILENAME` is a pre-defined variable in `awk`, use that  in your second print statement instead of `Simulation`.